# React и ввод данных в input

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Доброго времени суток! Делаю небольшое приложение на React, опыта пока немного. У меня два React-класса, один - это навигация, второй - форма редактирования данных. Странная ситуация - контроли в классе редактирования фокус ввода получают, но данные изменить невозможно. В чем может быть дело ? Код класса навигации

```
var MenuExample = React.createClass({
...
render: function() {
return (
  <div>
  ...
  <Content firstName={res.employees[active_index].firstName} lastName={res.employees[active_index].lastName} iddep={res.employees[active_index].iddepartment} id={res.employees[active_index].id}/>   
  </div>
    ); 

    }  
});
```

Теперь код класса ввода данных:

```
var Content = React.createClass({

render: function() {
var iddep_ = this.props.iddep;
var firstName_ = this.props.firstName;
var lastName_ = this.props.lastName;
return (
         <div>
          <p><label>id department</label></p><p><input type="text"  name="iddep" value={iddep_}/> </p>   
          <p><label>first name</label></p><p><input type="text" name="firstName" value={lastName_}/></p>
          <p><label>last name</label></p><p><input type="text" name="lastName" value={firstName_}/></p>
          <p><button onClick={this.clicked.bind()}>Изменить</button></p>
         </div> 
    ); 

}  
});
```

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные изменить невозможно, потому что вы никак не обрабатываете их изменение: `this.props.firstName`, например не меняется.

Почитайте больше о работе с [формами](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)